# Can not connect to internet server,

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, server

I am using CodeIgniter, I have developed user management in CodeIgniter when running it on my local server all things works perfectly but now I have uploaded it on my live server first time when I run it's working but when I do log in and when I click on some links in it show me this ERROR.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> ifixsoft.com refused to connect.
>
> Search Google for ipixsoft login
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: [This](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED-on-Chrome) can help you.

Comment: Are you allowing port 80 connections?

Comment: Thanks for replay. I am using live server not using local server